# How to Model below Hiearchy with OOP

Tags: java, object-oriented, inheritance, static

**Note** that I cannot use static inheritance due to language limitations (Java).

There is a general Building class. Each instance of `Building` has properties that exist regardless of instance variables (such as width, length, max level, BASE damage). There are numerous types of buildings, such as resource and defensive, and within those types, there are the actual buildings that a user would build (such as a lumber mill or cannon).

The problem is static inheritance. I cannot require subtypes of `Building` to have the static properties mentioned above.

What I have tried:

**1)** Using the singleton pattern to simulate static inheritance (as effectively, the instance patterns of a class that has one instance have the same functionality as static). However, I require to ability to generate instances of buildings on the spot (such as when a user builds a lumber mill, which would have a current level that is part of the instance, not the class). Therefore, this was ineffective.

**2)** Using enums to represent all buildings (so these enums would be `LUMBERMILL`, `ARCHER_TOWER`, etc). However, again, I require the ability to create multiple instances of these types of buildings. Enums are functionally equivalent to public static fields, therefore multiple instances cannot be created.

It is worth mentioning that I am using Java, so if any solutions require creating instances of generic types available at runtime, I am unable to do so.

**How can I simulate this hiearchy using OOP?**

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to formulate a reasonable answer.  Static inheritance is an *implementation detail;* the forbidding of its use seems like an odd stipulation.  Perhaps you can share a bit more about your specific problem?

Comment: @Robert Harvey, I believe in other languages static inheritance is not a limitation (SmallTalk?). However, in Java, static inheritance is part of the spec. Its a requirement that I (unfortunately) have to live with. I cannot use the modifiers `abstract` and `static` within the same signature. I said I'm using Java in the question, however I'll emphasize it at the top to make it clearer.

Comment: Why is static inheritance a factor here?  Why is it so prominent in your question?

Comment: `I require to ability to generate instances of buildings on the spot (such as when a user builds a lumber mill, which would have a current level that is part of the instance, not the class)` -- Factory or Abstract Factory patterns?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Each of my buildings has properties that belong to the class, not an instance, so they are static. I want to enforce the contract that any subtype of Building must have these properties. If I had the ability to use static inheritance, I could make a method such as `abstract static int getBuildingWidth()` within `Building` that all subtypes are required to implement. However, I can't do this, so the question is how to circumvent it. As for your factory or abstract factory response, I'll look into those (have heard of them but don't know what they are).

Comment: I strongly suspect that you don't need the `static` keyword to successfully accomplish what you want.  At the very worst, you'll be using composition with immutable objects, which is probably a far more tractable approach than trying to bend static inheritance to your will.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was trying to prevent. I'll try to make your suggestion of composition with immutable objects work, but I'm not only using `static` to represent immutability (so I'll see how it goes).

Comment: `static` doesn't have anything to do with immutability.  Sounds like you need to educate yourself a bit more about how the Java language works.

Comment: It looks to me you do not understand what static means and you just want constants instead. Are you mixing up variables and values?

Comment: I see absolutely no reason for static variables here. Just have 'width' etc class variables in the base Building class, then initialise them to the appropriate values for each building-type subclass in the constructor for that subclass. Or some sort of factory as suggested by @RobertHarvey could work as well.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have some properties that are tied to a building type and some properties that are tied to an instance of a building.

Would this kind of class structure work:

```
public class Building {
    private final BuildingType type;
    private int level;
    private int damage;
    // properties of a building
    ...
}

public enum BuildingType {
    LUMBERMILL(5, 4, 3, 0, ...), 
    ARCHER_TOWER(2, 2, 5, 100, ...),
    ...;
    private final int width;
    private final int length;
    private final int maxLevel;
    private final int baseDamage;
    // properties tied to the type of buildings
    ...
    private BuildingType(int width, int length, int maxLevel, int baseDamage, ...) {
        this.width = width;
        this.length = length;
        this.maxLevel = maxLevel;
        this.baseDamage = baseDamage;
        ...
    }
}
```

The BuildingType enum could be changed to a regular class to allow creating new building types dynamically and to allow moving data from source code to data files, which is often preferable.

---

If there were some global restrictions to the values of some attributes -- for instance, if the value of baseDamage should be greater than zero -- then those restrictions could be added in the part that initializes a BuildingType.

If the class BuildingType is an enum (like it is above), I don't see any benefit doing that. It's just code checking that some code 20 lines above doesn't contain a typo. That's not very productive. If, however, the attributes of BuildingTypes were read from a data file, then there should be code checking the values against such restrictions.

---

If your system of building types has a hierarchy, then you need your classes to represent that hierarchy. However, I would advice using composition instead of inheritance unless there is some polymorphic behavior involved. You should try to avoid the need to check the type of an object at runtime.

A simple solution could look like this:

```
public class Building {
    private final BuildingType type;
    ...
}

public class BuildingType {
    private final BuildingClass class;
    ...
}

public class BuildingClass {
    private final BuildingClass parentClass;
    ...
}
```

This design would allow an arbitrarily deep hierarchy of types of buildings. Each class of buildings and each type of building could have some data involved.

For example, an instance of a coal mine could have four objects involved:

- Building: the specific instance of coal mine
- BuildingType: coal mine
- BuildingClass: production/mine (two objects for two levels of hierarchy)

Comment: So is it alright that I have resource buildings with damage 0? Or defensive buildings with resource production rate 0? Seems like a design flaw, though I'm willing to make that sacrifice if I need to.

Comment: @MarDev I don't know what "damage" means in your context, but if there are restrictions to some attributes, you could write some code to make sure all attributes are legal.